# Discrete Kernel for Sequential Monte Carlo (population monte carlo)

Tags: bayesian, monte-carlo, importance-sampling, particle-filter

I'm attempting understand, and use, the population Monte Carlo algorithm found here https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.2256 for approximate Bayesian computation. However I think this is a general SMC question, or even SIS question. It's motivated by my wish to do parameter inference, when my parameters take values in a subset of $\mathbb{R}_{+}\times \mathbb{N}$.

At iteration $n-1$ we have some particles $\{X^{i}_{n-1}\}_{i=1}^{N}$. Say each $X_{n-1}^{i}\in\mathbb{R}_{+}\times \mathbb{N}$, then is there a 'standard' Markov kernel to obtain my next set of particles? If instead $X_{n-1}^{i}\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$, then I can use a Gaussian kernel and even optimise the parameters of this kernel (I'm not quite understanding this part yet but my references tell me it's true).

My naive (possibly incorrect approach) would be as follows. If $X_{n-1}^{i}=(Y_{n-1}^{i},Z_{n-1}^{i})$ then I'd let $Y_{n}^{i}\sim \tau^{-1}\mathcal{N}(Y_{n-1}^{i},1)$ and 
$$
Z_{n-1}^{i}\sim \frac{1}{2}\delta _{Z_{n-1}^{i}-1}+\frac{1}{2}\delta _{Z_{n-1}^{i}+1}.
$$
i.e. a simple random walk step. This at least would allow me to still calculate my importance weights recursively.

Can anyone tell me I'm definitely wrong, or give me a reference with some hints?

Comment: The problem with this random walk proposal on $Z$ is that it does not have the right support. Since population Monte Carlo and SMC are importance sampling techniques this invalidates the proposal.

Comment: Thanks for your response, do you have any hints on how to rectify this issue or a reference I could read more about it myself?

Comment: A first suggestion is to use a distribution on $Z$ that covers the entire range of possible values, possibly independently of the previous value of the particle.